# convert sql query to codeigniter active records

Tags: codeigniter-3

```
i want to convert this sql query to codeigniter active records 
SELECT`s.total`,`s.is_completed`,`p.tot`,`p.completed`,`st.uid`,`st.unm`,`sl.verify`,`sl.saldate` FROM (SELECT sum(`count`) As total, sum(`is_completed`) As is_completed, `user_id` AS stepid FROM stepvice) AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `id` AS uid,`name` AS unm from `staffcredentials`) As st ON `st.uid`='s.stepid' LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT sum(`count`) As tot, sum(`is_completed`) As completed, `user_id` AS pageid FROM pagevice) AS p ON `p.pageid`='s.stepid' LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `check` AS verify, `user_id` AS salid,`date` AS saldate  FROM `staffsalary`) As sl ON `sl.salid`='p.pageid' WHERE `st.uid`='$ids[$i]'"
```

when i include this query inside $this->db->query() it shows error but this query works perfectly in mysql

Comment: Try running this query directly in the Mysql console and see if there's any errors

Comment: this is the query i have run on sql with no error SELECT s.total,s.is_completed,p.total,p.is_completed,st.uid,st.unm,sl.verify FROM (SELECT sum(`count`) As total, sum(`is_completed`) As is_completed, `user_id` AS stepid FROM stepvice) AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN (select `id` AS uid,`name` AS unm from `staffcredentials`) As st ON st.uid=s.stepid LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT sum(`count`) As total, sum(`is_completed`) As is_completed, `user_id` AS pageid FROM pagevice) AS p ON p.pageid=s.stepid LEFT OUTER JOIN (select `check` AS verify, `user_id` AS salid FROM `staffsalary`) As sl ON sl.salid=p.pageid

Comment: Please update the question with the error you get after running this query with `$this->db->query()`

Comment: Unknown column 's.total' in 'field list' this is the error i got when i run this query with in $this->db->query(); for ($i=0; $i <count($ids) ; $i++) { 
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT `s.total`,`s.is_completed`,`p.tot`,`p.completed`,`st.uid`,`st.unm`,`sl.verify`,`sl.saldate` FROM (SELECT sum(`count`) As total, sum(`is_completed`) As is_completed, `user_id` AS stepid FROM stepvice) AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `id` AS uid,`name` AS unm from `staffcredentials`) As st ON `st.uid`='s.stepid' ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query contains

> ` (Grave accent)

instead of `'` (single quote)

That is the cause of error here most probably.

You should replace it with single quotes (`'`)

Try with this

```
SELECT s.total,s.is_completed,p.tot,p.completed,st.uid,st.unm,sl.verify,sl.saldate FROM (SELECT sum('count') As total, sum('is_completed') As is_completed, user_id AS stepid FROM stepvice) AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id AS uid,name AS unm from staffcredentials) As st ON st.uid=s.stepid LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT sum('count') As tot, sum('is_completed') As completed, user_id AS pageid FROM pagevice) AS p ON p.pageid=s.stepid LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT check AS verify, user_id AS salid,date AS saldate  FROM staffsalary) As sl ON sl.salid=p.pageid WHERE st.uid=$ids[$i]"
```

Comment: now it shows this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''staffcredentials') As st ON 'st.uid'='s.stepid' LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT sum('co' at line 1

Comment: did you try removing single quotes around `staffcredentials`

Comment: yes thank you, now it doesn't showing any database errors but it shows Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string and $result=$query->result();
   return $result; this is the way i used to get result of query

Comment: Yeah, that's because it returns an array made up with objects. You cannot directly get it as a string. try `var_dump($query->result())` and then `die()` to make sure what's the object is like

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> array(0) { } } this is the output i got when i var_dump. i use array push to get all the records using for loop and i got the results so i had stored in the form of $data['output'] and i var_dump as var_dump($data['output']);die;

Comment: Why does it return an empty array ?

Comment: when iam used this edited query in sql it also shows null results but the first query with ` (Grave accent) shows correct results

Comment: I updated the answer with an updated query. Try running it and let me know the result.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'check AS verify, user_id AS salid,date AS saldate FROM staffsalary) As sl ON sl' at line 1 also s.total,s.is_completed,p.tot,p.completed,st.uid,st.unm,sl.verify,sl.saldate
st.uid=s.stepid,p.pageid=s.stepid,sl.salid=p.pageid is in blue color in my model and now also Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string error is there